# Scikit-learn Standard Scaler

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I hope this problem was not touched on before. I have a data set consists of 18 columns. 14 columns have numerical data and 4 columns have categorical type. I will apply Linear Regression algorithms but before doing that I want to scale the numeric data. In order to do that I dropped the categorical ones first, scaled the numeric ones and then merge with the scaled one. The problem is that after merging the two sub-data sets, categorical data merges with train data set proportion.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=5)
X_train_sub = X_train[['waterfront','view', 'basement', 'renovated']]
col_names = list(X_train_sub)
for col in col_names:
  X_train_sub[col] = X_train_sub[col].astype('category',copy=False)
```

X_train_sub info()

```
X_train_sub.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 16209 entries, 10306 to 2915
Data columns (total 4 columns):
waterfront    16209 non-null category
view          16209 non-null category
basement      16209 non-null category
renovated     16209 non-null category
dtypes: category(4)
```

Scaling the Training Data after dropping off the categorical variables

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = X_train.drop(['waterfront','view', 'basement', 'renovated'], axis=1)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(X_scaled), 
columns=X_scaled.columns.values)
```

Add back the columns

```
X_scaled[['waterfront','view', 'basement', 'renovated']] = X_train_sub
X_scaled.info()

Data columns (total 18 columns):
bedrooms         16209 non-null float64
bathrooms        16209 non-null float64
sqft_living      16209 non-null float64
sqft_lot         16209 non-null float64
floors           16209 non-null float64
condition        16209 non-null float64
grade            16209 non-null float64
sqft_above       16209 non-null float64
yr_built         16209 non-null float64
zipcode          16209 non-null float64
lat              16209 non-null float64
long             16209 non-null float64
sqft_living15    16209 non-null float64
sqft_lot15       16209 non-null float64
waterfront       12143 non-null category
view             12143 non-null category
basement         12143 non-null category
renovated        12143 non-null category
dtypes: category(4), float64(14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an alignment problem. The following code destructed the original index

```
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(X_scaled), 
                        columns=X_scaled.columns.values)
```

try

```
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(X_scaled), 
                        columns=X_scaled.columns.values,
                        index=X_scaled.index)
```